# git rebase fatal: empty ident name not allowed

Tags: git

So I've seen this question asked and the resolution is always to update the 'user' settings with `git config`. I've done this and I'm still getting the error. Here is my output:

```
$ git config -l --global | grep user
user.email=A@B.com
user.name=A
$ git config -l --local | grep user
user.email=A@B.com
user.name=A
$ git rebase --continue
Applying: my commit message
fatal: empty ident name (for <A@B.com>) not allowed
```

Before this, I was on a branch, fetched master, and tried to rebase master into my branch. Something like this:

```
$ git checkout mybranch
$ git fetch origin
$ git rebase origin/master
```

Is it possible for something to be wrong on the remote server side? (e.g. my user account got messed up)

Comment: When you git-rebase a commit, it will be recommitted with the same name as the original one, so configuration options will not change that. You can trying with `git rebase -i` and do a `fixup` or an `edit` to the offending commit to overwrite the _author_ name.

Comment: I'm still getting the same problem after running `$ git rebase --abort; $ git rebase -i origin/master` then I changed my entries to `edit` and I got the following output: `fatal: empty ident name (for <A@B.com>) not allowed`

Answer (score 0):

Update July 2018: with Git 2.19, `git rebase` will use `--allow-empty-message` by default.
See "[Rebasing a git history with empty commit messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48977896/6309)".

---

Original answer (2016):

> I'm still getting the same problem after running

```
$ git rebase --abort
$ git rebase -i origin/master
```

> then I changed my entries to edit

It would be best to, after aborting the rebase, edit your config and *then* try the rebase.

---

Note that Git 2.11 (Q4 2016) will be less picky.
See [commit 1e461c4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e461c4f1fc43a00c7f576a111b4f002ba2d2557) (29 Jul 2016) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ae1ae60](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ae1ae600db5e159c4563ee080531b9500c26d635), 21 Sep 2016)</sup>

> ### rebase-interactive: drop early check for valid ident
>
> Since the very inception of interactive-rebase in [1b1dce4 (Teach rebase an interactive mode, 2007-06-25, Git 1.5.3-rc0)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b1dce4bae760248a1fc3e29548a72c446e77270), there has been a preemptive check, before looking at any commits, to see whether the user has a valid name/email combination.
>
> This is convenient, because it means that we abort the operation before even beginning (rather than just complaining that we are unable to pick a particular commit).
>
> However, it does the wrong thing when the rebase does not actually need to generate any new commits (e.g., a fast-forward with no commits to pick, or one where the base stays the same, and we just pick the same commits without
>   rewriting anything).
>   In this case it may complain about the lack of ident, even though one would not be needed to complete the operation.
>
> This may seem like mere nit-picking, but because interactive rebase underlies the "`preserve-merges`" rebase, somebody who has set "`pull.rebase`" to "`preserve`" cannot make even a fast-forward pull without a valid ident, as we bail before even realizing the fast-forward nature.
>
> This commit drops the extra ident check entirely. This means we rely on individual commands that generate commit objects to complain.
>
> The user can then manually commit or even "`git rebase --continue`" after setting up their ident (or providing it as a one-off on the command line).