# How doyou Amend the last commit message in git?

Tags: git, git-svn

I am using `git-svn` and I know that svn does not support changing commits

if I haven't yet run `git svn dcommit` can i still change the last commit message, i left something out of it.

If so, how do you amend the last commit message?

EDIT:

i figured out i can do `git commit --amend` but is there any problem doing this using svn backend?

Comment: This question has been answered in [another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git)

Comment: is there any problem doing that with git-svn. My guess says no, since i haven't dcommit-ed it yet, but I'm unsure how it handles history with that.

Comment: As long as you haven't dcommitted yet, there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: @JoshuaRogers: I would accept that as an answer.

Comment: No.  When you git svn dcommit, the svn bridge will take all of the changes that have been made since you have last dcommitted and post them back.  As long as you have not already dcommitted, svn will be unaware that you have changed anything.  You can use git as normal.

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with svn if you have already updated svn. There is no practical way of rewriting history in svn.

Comment: but if i haven't yet, will it affect anything. Like would it try to commit it then rewrite it and fail? Is this a safe thing to do, pre svn commit, but not after. Is that correct?

Comment: correct. Once something is in SVN, it's not trivial to back out.

Comment: Then why not share the non-trivial solution?