# Firstly I commited new repo in git with master branch and now I cant commit

Tags: git, git-pull

Firstly I commited with master branch now I am in main branch and unable to change to master branch. Moreover if I tried to commit to my repo through main branch the following errors it shows:-

```
$ git push --set-upstream https://github.com/manvith22/Evernote-clone.git main

To https://github.com/manvith22/Evernote-clone.git
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/manvith22/Evernote-clone.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

abc@MA MINGW64 ~/react-redux-hooks (main)
    $ git pull <remote> master:dev
bash: remote: No such file or directory

abc@MA MINGW64 ~/react-redux-hooks (main)

    $ git pull <main> master:dev

bash: main: No such file or directory

abc@MA MINGW64 ~/react-redux-hooks (main)

    $ git pull <evernote> master:dev

There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> main
```

Comment: It is `main`, not `master`.

Comment: This is an extremely common question. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to-remote or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399804/updates-were-rejected-because-the-tip-of-your-current-branch-is-behind-its-remot or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684352/what-does-git-push-non-fast-forward-updates-were-rejected-mean or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794413/failed-to-push-some-refs-to-githeroku-com or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832348/git-push-rejected-error-failed-to-push-some-refs or many others...

Comment: https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/

Comment: Also, an important point of terminology: you _commit_ changes in your local repository. The commands you show are when you're *pushing* the work you've already committed - that is, *sharing* or *synchronizing* it with a remote server. Understanding the difference will be very important when you're learning about how to use git.

Answer (score 1):

The `<`/`>` brackets mean it's a placeholder for whichever branch you really mean. You don't need to type the brackets out; you just want

```
git pull https://github.com/manvith22/Evernote-clone.git main
```

or most likely just

```
git pull
```

will do.

However, looking at the repository https://github.com/manvith22/Evernote-clone there are two branches; `master` *and* `main`. You'll need to talk with the other people working on the repo to choose which branch you'll be using.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between what is committed on origin and your local, thus the first push failed.

You can bring change from remote using `git pull --rebase` (assuming you are already on `main` branch)

After that you can push you changes with `git push` command.

PS: using `<` is used for providing input from file and `>` to write output to file. By running `git pull <remote> master:dev` you are saying, read from file `remote` and write output to file `master:dev`