# Revert a remote merge

Tags: git

I am working on a branch called Lion, I mistakenly done this:

```
git push origin lion:master
```

instead of

```
git push eng lion:master
```

Basically the second line is for pushing the lion branch to a staging heroku app but I mistakenly merge all my code to into origin master.

How can I revert than? I have about 200 commits in my branch.

Greg

Comment: See if you find anything helpful in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git), one of the most popular SO questions of all time (at least up until now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command 'git reset' takes an optional commit argument.  So, if you have access to the origin repository you could try:

```
git reset [--soft | --mixed] <last-good-commit>           # in the remote/origin repository
```

If you don't have access to the repository you should be able to do:

```
git checkout -b rework <last-good-commit>
git push origin rework:master                                   # The push merge will produce a commit that works back to <last-good-commit>
```

Comment: I get "! [rejected] rework -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:....'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected....

Answer (score 2):

Assuming no-one else has already gone and got the new changes:

1) If you have direct access to the `origin` repository, you can do a `git reset --hard <commit ID>` on the relevant branch in `origin`.

2) Alternatively, you could do a `git push -f` with the old commit ID perhaps.

Comment: It doesn't if you do `git reset --hard <commit ID>`, which was what I was driving at.