# After git commit, Is it possible to revert only one file?

Tags: git, github

I have two commits merged into a single commit with specific change id

```
commit fea9c375f216a75c6a2a2fcc9c903a5992d3679e
    adding Field
    Change-Id: Id07dd67b412d56f64e05246ea0b87924f8a803cb
```

Now i have 5 files commited in this..

I have to revert only one file in this commit. Is it possible?

```
git reflog
fea9c37 HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to ORIG_HEAD

6bf010f HEAD@{1}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/dev

6bf010f HEAD@{2}: rebase -i (pick): adding Field

2a0b1d7 HEAD@{3}: rebase -i (start): checkout remotes/gerrit/dev

fea9c37 HEAD@{4}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/dev

fea9c37 HEAD@{5}: rebase -i (squash): adding Field

e2f9b47 HEAD@{6}: rebase -i (start): checkout refs/remotes/origin/dev

27cc4f3 HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from bf4a4564ed3ddcb1de1114f2d020d65ead2e9999 to dev

bf4a456 HEAD@{8}: rebase -i (start): checkout refs/remotes/origin/dev

27cc4f3 HEAD@{9}: commit: printField

e2f9b47 HEAD@{10}: commit (amend): adding Field

afddac7 HEAD@{11}: reset: moving to ORIG_HEAD

a614916 HEAD@{12}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/dev

a614916 HEAD@{13}: rebase -i (pick): adding Field

c766b57 HEAD@{14}: rebase -i (start): checkout remotes/gerrit/dev

afddac7 HEAD@{15}: commit: adding Field

bf4a456 HEAD@{16}: pull: Fast-forward

5d63ab1 HEAD@{17}: checkout: moving from master to dev
```

I tried 
`git reset fea9c37 <filename>`

but the changes are still present in the file.

How do i revert this?

Comment: I think this question is repeated here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/15321456/1860929

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove files from Git commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481639/remove-files-from-git-commit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git checkout` to revert a file to a previous commit.

e.g.:
`git checkout Id07dd67b412d56f64e05246ea0b87924f8a803cb path/to/file`

(where `Id07d...` is the commit you want to reset the file to -- before the change)