# GIT rm command removes my file from my project

Tags: git

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm

Say I run a commit but then I realize that I have just committed files that I don't wish to commit

if I run git rm on a file, it will literally delete the file from my project and the filesystem.

I just want to remove the file from the most recent commit and stop tracking it - basically gitignoring retroactively!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git rm` has done what it is expected to do. To stop tracking the file you need to add the file path in your [.gitignore file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

and to revert the changes back, use

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

Comment: yes but what if I dont want to reset all the files just the one or two files that I wish to gitignore?

Comment: The link in the answer, will show many possible ways to ignore the git file by path/pattern. You can also make gitignore to track only files you want to track like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189437/explain-gitignore-pattern-matching/33190653#33190653 but I highly recommend not to use this pattern. If you like to reset only particular file check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/215731/1699979

Answer (score 3):

You have to edit or undo the last commit.

Have a look at a similar Question:
[Remove files from Git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481639/remove-files-from-git-commit)