# .gitignore whitelisting vim folder

Tags: git, vim, gitignore

I am tracking and versioning my dotfiles with the help of `vcsh` and `mr`. As suggested, i let vcsh create a predefined .gitignore-file to ignore unneeded files outside of my .vim-directory. 
However, now i want to modify it so it would not ignore my `.vimrc` nor my `~/.vim`-folder with all its subdirectories.

Currently, this is the content of my .gitignore:

```
*
!/.gitignore.d
!/.gitignore.d/vim
!/.vimrc
!/.vim/
!/.vim/**
```

However, it still ignores all subfolders of the vim-folder, despite the last line of the .gitignore. I have no idea why. Do you?

Comment: Is this the only .gitignore file in tree? You can place a .gitignore file at any location, not only at the root of your repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, it still ignores all subfolders of the vim-folder, despite
>   the last line of the .gitignore. I have no idea why. Do you?

As explained in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189437/explain-gitignore-pattern-matching/33190653#33190653) this type of .gitignore pattern i.e. `*` in the first line, will make git to track only those files, which you will explicitly say to track using `!` opertor. Please go through that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189437/explain-gitignore-pattern-matching/33190653#33190653), which I have explained in detail. It belongs to 3rd point of it i.e.

3. **Pattern with slash and special character (*/?)** : If the pattern ends like the 1st example you gave, `images/*.*` It works as specified in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

   > Example: "Documentation/*.html" matches "Documentation/git.html" but not
   >   "Documentation/ppc/ppc.html" or "tools/perf/Documentation/perf.html".

So git will track only the files under `images/` in your case `vim/` not its subfolders. If you like to add all sub folders, add all the folders in the .gitignore file or avoid using this kind of gitignore pattern `*`.

Comment: `gitignore(5)` specifically calls out `**` as doing what the OP seems to expect though: A trailing "/**" matches everything inside. For example, "abc/**" matches all files inside directory "abc", relative to the location of the .gitignore file, with infinite depth.