# Exclude subfolders but keep files

Tags: git

I'm trying to make a `.gitignore`

I have a directory like :

```
.
folder
folder/readme.txt
folder/xxx.txt
folder/sub1
folder/sub2
```

**I don't know the name/amount of files or subfolders in `folder/`**

I'd like to make a rule that ignore all subfolders in `folder/` but that keep all the files `folder/file.smthg` so I can only see :

```
.
folder
folder/readme.txt
folder/xxx.txt
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files)

Comment: @Synaps I don't think it is, as I explained in the answer `I don't know the name/amount of files or subfolders in folder/` therefore I cannot make a rule that exclude them from the ignoring pattern, as the answers suggest in the question you linked

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/a/987162/4088809

Comment: I recommend not to use the first answer suggested by Synaps, because you may run into this [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189437/explain-gitignore-pattern-matching/33190653#33190653), instead, I suggest go with this [pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16318111/1699979) in the same question.

Comment: @TaharBakir : please refer to the comment I done above yours

Comment: @rajuGT : please refer to my first comment, this question is not a duplicate of the one linked by Synaps or rajuGT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude folders using `*/`

So your gitignore could be something like this

```
folder/*/
```

Comment: It works :) I'll accept the answer when I'll be back from lunch ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Wildcards?

```
    folder/*/*
```

You can also use the double wildcard (**) to match all level of subdirectories :

```
    **/folder/test/
```