# gitignore everything except a symlink

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following folder structure:

```
node_modules/
  my_symlink_to_lib
  folder_a/
  folder_b/
lib/
  (some files here)
```

I want to ignore everything inside `node_modules` except the symlink:

```
# Doesn't work
node_modules/*
!node_modules/my_symlink_to_lib

# Doesn't work
node_modules/*
!node_modules/my_symlink_to_lib
!node_modules/my_symlink_to_lib/*
```

I have tried several other stuff, `node_modules/my_symlink_to_lib` doesn't end up in untracked files.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189437/explain-gitignore-pattern-matching

Comment: No, my globs were good. The problem was `.gitignore_global`. I wasn't aware/forgot that it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you don't have something like the following in `.gitignore_global` file:

```
# ignores the whole folder so negation won't work in local .gitignore
node_modules
```