# git ignore all files except extension but ignore pattern of extension

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a folder containing two types of files that are required to compile a software program. When the software program is compiled, it auto-generates files I do not wish to track, but one of those files is of the same extension of the files required to compile the program I have:

```
# ignore everything (to ignore all auto-generated files without listing their extensions)
*

# but do not ignore (required to compile)
!*.abc
!*.xyz

# but ignore if file name matches pattern (auto-generated file after compilation)
*generic.abc
```

Is there a way to ignore everything, except two specified file extensions, but ignore the specified file extension if it is preceded by a certain naming convention? Note: there is unique text before the "generic.abc" file, which is why I want to ignore that "generic.abc" convention. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If possible I would recommend making your exclude rules more explicit.  But if you really want this approach of ignoring everything except what you while-list, then the rules you specified seem to work (at least in quick tests I threw together).  I assume you have found some problem when you try to use those rules; what unexpected behavior did you observe?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger It seems to be tracking the generic.abc file...it was initially tracked before I added the above code to the .gitignore file but I removed it with `git rm --cached generic.abc` but it still appears when I type `git status`

Comment: After you `git rm --cached generic.abc`, does it show up as `deleted` (indicating only that it was in the previous commit) or as an untracked file?

Answer (score 1):

I had left out one * symbol after the file name and extension. I found this link to be helpful [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189437/explain-gitignore-pattern-matching).

This is the revised .gitignore file and this seems to work.

```
# ignore everything (to ignore all auto-generated files without listing their extensions)
*

# but do not ignore (required to compile)
!*.abc
!*.xyz

# but ignore if file name matches pattern (auto-generated file after compilation) -> HERE IS THE ADDITIONAL * after .abc!
*generic.abc*
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works exactly like you posted.