# How to exclude all subfolders with a specific name in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have several subfolders in various parts of my project called "autosave" and I want .gitignore to ignore any subfolder called "autosave" regardless of where it is in the project, how would I do this?

I am kinda new with git but I did try */autosave/   but that doesn't appear to work. Also, some are capitalized and some aren't (Autosave and autosave).

Comment: Maybe this is what you looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189437/explain-gitignore-pattern-matching

Answer (score 1):

A simple line should be enough

```
autosave/
Autosave/
```

That will ignore any `autosave` *folder* (anywhere).
It should be the equivalent of `**/autosave/`

See [`gitignore` pattern format](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format):

> If the pattern ends with a slash, it is removed for the purpose of the following description, but it would only find a match with a directory.
>
> In other words, `foo/` will match a *directory* `foo` and paths underneath it, but will not match a regular file or a symbolic link foo (this is consistent with the way how pathspec works in general in Git).

Comment: doh, i knew it would be simple, thank you so much, VonC!