# Remove files from last git commit

Tags: git, version-control

This is not the same as [Remove files from Git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481639/remove-files-from-git-commit), because all the answers there doesn't work for this case. 
So here is the question,

Before `git commit`, we use `git add`. The problem is when we are doing `git add`, sometimes we forgot to check and only when doing `git commit` did we realized that those files should not be picked up by `git add` are being added and committed.

This is the reason why all the answers there doesn't work, because `git reset HEAD^` or alike does not work for files newly being picked up, and have not git history beforehand. I learned it the hard way.

So, any solution for this case? Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this after you've committed:

```
git rm --cached <files-you-didn't-want>
git commit --amend
```

Note that if you've already pushed the erroneous commit then you'll need to do a forced non-fast-forward push in order to remove the erroneous commit from a remote.

Answer (score 1):

`git commit --amend` when you commit too early and possibly forget to add some files, or you mess up your commit

Answer (score 0):

What about `git reset <file>`? Or just `git reset` to remove all files from index from the last `git add`

Answer (score 0):

Use     'git rm --cached name_of_file ' Command. This will ignore the files even if they were added before with ' git add'.