# Git Commit Issue : Updated File not Push

Tags: git

Issue is ,

My Previous comiit have one zip file which is very large therefore it will not successfully push. but after delete this file whenever i make second commit then previous commit zip file also consider inside that.
Previously i commit and Push files and folder but inside that one 7 Gb zip file is also there so that File push is not completed. 
therefor i removed this zip file and try to push again but its also consider this zip file .

Anyone have an any idea please share with me.

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481639/remove-files-from-git-commit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: Guys, There are so many option on reference link , Can you please provide hint which one isuseful command for solve this. Thanks

Comment: And is there any affect on remote site ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove files from Git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481639/remove-files-from-git-commit)

Comment: any idea about below command:
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch pi/data/node-login.0'

git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch pi/data/node-login.1'

git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch pi/data/local.0'

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove this *.zip file from the staging area?

If you added a file by mistake, you can unstage it (but keep local changes) by saying

```
git reset HEAD path/to/file
```

After this, you should add the *.zip file to the `.gitignore` file to keep it permanently out of your repo.

Comment: i don't want this zip file and i already deleted from my server. but how can i do next commit without consider this zip file because it will always consider in next all new commit so this process is not completed every time.