# git does not allow me to push files despite changes in folder

Tags: git, push

I get the following error:

```
remote: error: File AllFiles/Test.zip is 130.15 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

The thing is that I have removed this folder long time ago, and then used "git add ." as well as "git add --all" before committing - still git is convinced that this "large" file is in the folder and does not let me push to master...what can I do?

Comment: add the file to your .gitignore

Comment: Can I add a non-existent file to .gitignore though?

Comment: Yes, also check your committed files, if you accidentally committed the file you can reset your head and remove the file.

Comment: It just finished and same error...I used git reset --hard..is there anything else I should try...it's slowly driving me crazy..what a strange error

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481639/remove-files-from-git-commit for your reset

Answer (score 1):

What you need to understand why this is failing and why [the duplicate that phd linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository) *is* a duplicate, is to realize that `git push` does not push *files*.  What `git push` pushes are *commits*.  Commits contain files—each commit is a complete snapshot of *all* files—so this means that at least one of the *commits* you are pushing has the large file.  When you go to remove the file from the *current* commit, it's not there, so that means that at least one of the commits you are pushing *doesn't* have the file.  This is not self contradictory: you are pushing *at least two commits*, and *at least one* has the big file, while the last one does not have the big file.

Since `git push` pushes commits (and files just come along for the ride), you must change *which commits you push*.  You do this by replacing your previous history—your previous series of commits that you added—with a new, different history: a new, different series of commits you have added.  There are many ways to do that.

To see which commits `git push` will push, run `git fetch` first (so that your repository has all the commits that the upstream repository has), then run `git log HEAD@{upstream}..HEAD`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, add this file to your .gitignore. Then you gotta remove the file from your cache, then you can git add . and then git push.

```
    git rm -r --cached .
    git add .
    git commit -m "Your commit message."
    git push
```

Comment: Did that, but guess what it says:fatal: pathspec 'Test.zip' did not match any files

Comment: try *.zip unless you have other zip files you need.

Comment: It ignores two other files, but no word of "Test.zip" (which it is still finding though when I try to push): git rm -r --cached *.zip
rm 'AllFiles/Archive.zip'
rm 'AllFiles/ver-4b.zip'

Comment: Last thing I know to try is "git rm -r --cached ." the dot with remove all cached files and then "git add ." will build a fresh cache.

Comment: same same:/.....

Comment: When you run git status, does the zip file show up (in green)? (Im assuming you're using command line.

Comment: This is when I check the status the output: On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean