# How to exclude files from git commit?

Tags: git, git-stash

I am working with a bunch of files but would not like to commit some of them.

Rather than commit each file individually is there a way I can exclude the files I do not want to commit?

From reading similar questions on SO, I've tried various instances of `git stash` but have not been able to get them to work, eg:

```
git stash file.ext
git stash -- file.ext
git stash push "file.ext"
git stash push -- file.ext
```

Would anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the filenames/ directories/ extensions in a `.gitignore` file in your repository directory.

Ex:

```
# ignore files with extention .ext
*.ext
# ignore directory
some_dir/
# ignore files in a directory but keep particular ones
some_other_dir/*
!some_other_dir/*.tar.gz
```

However if you have already done a commit with files that you don't want to be in the git repo, take a look at  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481639/remove-files-from-git-commit)

Answer (score 0):

If those files:

- are *already* versioned, and you need to keep them in the repository (meaning they are not private files to be ignored)
- can be changed locally, but should *not* be added/commited

You can try, from "[Difference Between '`assume-unchanged`' and '`skip-worktree`'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23806990/6309)"

```
git update-index --skip-worktree -- a file
git update-index --no-skip-worktree -- a file
```