# Cannot ignore a log file in git repository

Tags: git

I have really strange case, when I cannot to ignore a log file "SE.log" in my git repository. I have created "tmp.log" file and it to ignore properly.

[image]

my .gitignore file:

[image]

Comment: Did you ever add or commit se.log?

Comment: hi , not sure that correct understood you. Can you please explain more detailed what you mean ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `SE.log` has already been committed, you need to do a:

```
git rm -rf --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "SE.log is now ignored"
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove your file from commit list using

```
git rm --cached
```

and then commit.

See this [Remove files from Git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481639/remove-files-from-git-commit)