# How to drop file added in git after the push(GitLab)

Tags: git, gitlab

I added file and push it.
I realize later that the file2 should not be added. How could I do please?

**Code**

```
git add f1.txt
git add f2.txt
git commit -m 'add f1'
git push origin feature_1
```

I did

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git reset HEAD path/to/f2
git commit -m 'add f1'
```

and im still having the file in my Merge Request on GIT.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove files from Git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481639/remove-files-from-git-commit)

Comment: @ChristianBaumann no :/ im still getting problems

Comment: @ChristianBaumann im still having the file :/

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure nobody has seen your push, you can do:

1. `git reset HEAD~1`
2. `git add file1.txt`
3. `git commit -m 'add f1'`
4. `git push -f`

But you need to be very carefull when force-pushing. Make sure nobodys work based on the old commit!

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to change **the latest commit**, you could try following solution.

Remove file that you want to delete.

```
git rm f2.txt
```

The command removes the file from the repo but **also deletes it from the local file system**. To remove the file from the repo and not delete it from the local file system, you could use:

```
git rm --cached f2.txt
```

After, you use:

```
git commit --amend
```

Finally, you use:

```
git push --force
```