# Changing content from an unpushed git commit in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I've made changes in a project in Visual Studio and committed them. It's connected to my GitHub repository.
Now, I haven't pushed it, because it won't work. After further investigation, I found that I accidentally added a huge file in my commit, which Visual Studio now tries to push up to my GitHub Repo.
But since it's such a huge file, it won't be uploaded and I dont know how to delete it from that commit.

So I would like to know:
How to access and modify/delete **files** from a **non-pushed** commit in Visual Studio?

And if that is not an option, how should I proceed otherwise? I already made more changes in the project, so I maybe have to do a rebase or something?

I found other threads, but those we're about changing the message, not the files themself, or [they were about an already pushed commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481639/remove-files-from-git-commit).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can use [`amend` within VS](https://saraford.net/2017/03/15/how-to-amend-changes-to-your-code-in-your-most-recent-commit-074/). Change what you want to change and in the `Team Explorer - Changes` window click `Actions` and `Amend Previous Commit`. This will change the last commit and rewrites it with your changes (amend).

Comment: Oh man you really helped my out there! Thank you so much!!!
Would you turn your comment into an answer, if its appropriate?

Comment: Sure, I've added this as answer 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [amend within VS](https://saraford.net/2017/03/15/how-to-amend-changes-to-your-code-in-your-most-recent-commit-074/).

Change what you want to change and in the `Team Explorer - Changes` window click `Actions` and `Amend Previous Commit`.

This will change the last commit and rewrites it with your changes (amend).

On the CLI, this would look like the following: `git commit --amend` ([with options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---amend) to change the message too)
The documentation is pretty good on that topic:

- [Git Basics - Undoing Things](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things)
- [Git Tools - Rewriting History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#_git_amend)

Answer (score 0):

- Navigate to Git Repository
- Right click on commit and select 'View Commit Details'
- In the right panel , select Amend Message
- Change message and then Push