# Is there anyway to squash and merge in SourceTree UI?

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using SourceTree Windows version.

One feature that I can't seem to find is the squash and merge; when I finish my work on a branch, I want to merge it into the main branch and I just want the main branch to have one commit, to keep the commit history uncluttered.

It seems that I need to use the command line to do it? ie: `git merge --squash`? But is there an UI way of doing it?

The [interactive rebase function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18349412/3834) seems to work for squash, but not exactly `squash and merge`.

Comment: To my knowledge it's not implemented in Sourcetree.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Squash in SourceTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348330/squash-in-sourcetree)

Comment: @TimSylvester, you are putting forward a link that I don't find helpful ( and I've already explained why)

Comment: That's how you do it in SourceTree, so this is a duplicate.  Of course a UI is not exactly like command line, but if you have a particular difference in mind, you'll need to be more specific.  I just squashed a branch down to one commit with interactive rebase and then merged it and didn't see any difference from a command-line or GitHub squash-merge.