# Git force merge

Tags: git, github

I am wondering what I am supposed to do in order to force a merge from a dev branch into my master branch? Using 'git merge dev' results in quite a number of conflicts. However, I don't want to handle them individually. Instead, I simply want to use all the files from my dev branch and merge it into master. But this "forced merge" is not as easy as I thought. Can somebody please point me into the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean with 'forced merge'? You are getting conflicts because git is not able to sort stuff through. You can always use options for merge to tell it to take the version of a certain branch where there's a conflict: `-Xours` or `-Xtheirs`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10697551/1375964 can use a recursive 'use -ours' strategy. https://stackoverflow.com/q/17667023/1375964 -you may want to just change what master is pointing to. Proceed with caution if you share this repository

Comment: @eftshift0 I stumbled across those options. But to be honest, I didn't fully understand which one to use in my case. I basically would like my dev branch to become my "master". That's what I meant with "force merge". So, which branch is "ours" and which branch is "theirs"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I simply want to use all the files from my dev branch

If you mean you want to use *all* the files from your dev branch - i.e. any changes made on the `master` branch since the branches diverged should be undone - then there are a couple of ways.

*merge -s ours*

You could

```
git checkout dev
git merge -s ours master
git checkout master
git merge dev
```

This is a bit round-about, because there is no "theirs" strategy.  (There is a "theirs" strategy *option* for the default merge strategy, but it would still try to apply changes from `master` as long as they don't conflict with changes from `dev`; if what you want is to *just* keep the `dev` versions, that won't work.)  So you use the `ours` strategy to create a merge commit between `master` and `dev` with the `dev` versions of all files, then fast-forward `master` onto that merge.

That means the order of parents will be reversed on the merge commit, which is something you usually wouldn't notice, but it could matter in some cases (like if you use `--first-parent` on logs or something).

*commit-tree*

If the order of parents matter, you could resort the plumbing command `commit-tree`

```
git checkout master
git merge $(git commit-tree dev -p master -p dev -m "merging dev over master")
```

*history rewrite*

The potential down-side to the above methods is that they produce a merge commit that may not be intuitive, in that its result ignores the changes from one side of the merge (whereas a merge is expected to combine the changes from both sides).  Because your merge would conflict under the normal strategy, it's not as big a problem as it could be, but still some people would categorize it as an "evil merge".  If you want to avoid that, the other option is to rewrite history.

That has a down side as well, particularly if you use this repo to collaborate with other developers.  You can read about the problem (and generally how to solve it) in the `git rebase` docs under "recovering from upstream rebase".  (While the docs refer to the problem as "upstream rebase", it really applies to any history rewrite of a shared branch.)

If you decide that a history rewrite makes sense, then the simplest thing is just to move the `master` branch so that it points to the same commit as `dev`.

```
git checkout dev
git branch -f master
```

Comment: `ours` and `theirs` is always confusing to me... Perhaps a reference to the docs of strategies `recursive-ours` and `ours` would help.

Comment: @Mark Adelsberger Thanks for the great write-up. The 'merge -s ours' way did the trick for me.