# How can I move origin/master back to the latest commit?

Tags: git

I'm trying to clean up the repo of this place and I want to move "master" branch back some commits and then up to the latest.

Due to just bad general code practices before my time at where I am, "master" branch was never followed and instead custom branch names were used. I'm trying to clean up the code base by moving master back to the top, however I'm unsure how to achieve what I want to do.

The commit structure is something like this where `O` shows what's been worked on, `A` is a branch off, `B` is a branch off, and `M` is where Master was left.

```
O-O-O-O-X-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-0 (top)
         \
          A-A-A-A
             \
              B-M
                 \
                  Z
```

What I want to do is first move the Master tag back to the `X` and then move it to the top of the commit list.

I'm wondering if a rebase would achieve this? I'm not sure. What I've tried to do is make a branch off the current master (`Z`), then reset master back to the `X` commit with:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

But this moves the `master` branch to `X` and leaves `origin/master` at the new branch off `Z` so when I try to pull master to the top it tries to pull off `Z` and not `X`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working using a [combination of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667023/git-how-to-reset-origin-master-to-a-commit) and the `rebase` command:

1. On master branch (`M`), create a new branch (`Z`) so as to save a copy of that master
2. Find the commit you wish to move master BACK IN TIME to (`X`): `git reset --hard <commit_id>`
3. `git push --force origin master` to make `X` origin/master
4. Checkout latest working branch (branch at top) --> `git checkout <top_branch>`
5. `git rebase <top_branch> master`