# How to undo the initial commit on a remote repository in git?

Tags: git, git-push, git-amend

If my very first commit is wrong, yet pushed to a (currently private) remote, how do I undo that commit on the remote?

I'm guessing I can just amend and then push --force?

Comment: It's rare to really need to wipe out a commit.  Just add other commits that fix your repo and brings it to the state you want it to be. (Unless of course you've done something like committed and pushed up passwords or the like).

Comment: I agree with @dkinzer The operation in the answer works, but it is one of those operations that you should have a clear answer as to why you are using versus just adding a new commit. As with any destructive operation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to revert initial git commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632191/how-to-revert-initial-git-commit)

Answer (score 20):

By deleting your `HEAD` you can restore your repository to a new state, where you can create a new initial commit:

```
git update-ref -d HEAD
```

After you create a new commit you will need to force it to the remote in order to overwrite the previous initial commit:

```
git push --force origin
```

Comment: Getting `remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544139/how-to-force-push-a-reset-to-remote-repository

Comment: error: src refspec refs/heads/master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs

Answer (score 1):

If you've just one commit (initial commit), you can do as

```
git commit --amend
git push --force origin
```

Comment: You'll need a `git add` up front if you're actually adding or modifying files to the commit (as opposed to just fixing the message).

Comment: fatal: You have nothing to amend.