# How can I delete the first commit on my repos history?

Tags: git, github, git-log

I've created a new repository in GitHub, but unfortunately I sent the first commit with **node_modules**
In the second one I removed the node_modules and sent the .gitignore file that avoids to commit all the node_modules since that second commit.

After several more commits in the progress, I've found out that the repository size was big because that initial commit that had all the node_modules.

So, my question is: how can I delete that first commit from the log history to reduce the repository size?

Note: I don't care about the first commit history progress because I have much more progress in the subsequents commits

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove a commit on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edit the root commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119480/edit-the-root-commit-in-git)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `git rebase -i --root` and squash the commit removing the `node_modules` folder with the first commit.

Comment: This is a correct answer. To Leonardo: pay close attention to the fact you do not actually want to _delete_ your root commit; you instead want its changes to be integrated with the next one — precisely as explained here.

Answer (score 0):

Git uses a tree organization that is only allowed to be added new nodes (commits). If you really want to delete a wrongly pushed commit you must update your repository locally and than force push to the according remote. I found an issue talking about it.

[How to undo the initial commit on a remote repository in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874613/how-to-undo-the-initial-commit-on-a-remote-repository-in-git)

Answer (score -2):

use `git revert <commit_id_to_be_reverted>`

Comment: This won't remove the commit.