# Git - move commit within branch, then insert branches

Tags: git, version-control, merge, branch, commit

Have looked around and can't find the answer to this! I am a complete git n00b and really grateful for anyone who can give me some pointers.

I initially had one long branch of commits in my repository and I wanted to change the message I had assigned to a previous commit (master~14) in the branch

So I did

```
git checkout master~14
git commit --amend -m "added the new description for the commit bla bla bla"
```

Unfortunately now I was placed into detached head mode
So then I panicked a bit and created a new branch so that I wouldn't loose the ref to this commit

```
git branch detached
```

Now I have a situation like this, where I have master~14 at the top of the tree on its own branch, and I want to put it back where it was in the tree, without causing any conflicts or overwriting anything

```
+        [detached] xxxxx
  *    + [master] xxxxx
  *    + [master^] xxxxx
  *    + [master~2] xxxxx
  *    + [master~3] xxxxx
  *    + [master~4] xxxxx
  *    + [master~5] xxxxx
  *    + [master~6] xxxxx
  *    + [master~7] xxxxx
  *    + [master~8] xxxxx
  *    + [master~9] xxxxx
  *    + [master~10] xxxxx
  *    + [master~11] xxxxx
  *    + [master~12] xxxxx
  *    + [master~13] xxxxx
  *    + [master~14] xxxxx
```

I would also like (after this is resolved) to branch off my commits from master~14..master~5 as one new tree and finally master~4..master as another tree.

Comment: What I should have done to rename the commit message in the first place is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

q1:

```
git checkout master
```

This would return you back to the master tip

or use

```
git reflog
```

or `git reflog show master`

to see how the pointers were moving

But better approach to the whole stuff would be

```
git rebase -i master~14
```

then mark the necessary commit to stop for amending, then you wouldn't be in detached HEAD state

q2:
To me it sounds like you want master~14..master~5 and master~4..master to start from master~15
if that's correct (i will create named branches for simplicity):

```
git branch feature1 master~5
git branch master15back master~15
git rebase --onto master15back feature1 master
```

see [git rebase doc](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help. 

For (a) 
What I actually ended up doing was: 
git branch -D detached
Then I re-did the rename following the advice here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git

Answer (score 0):

For q1,  you can try git rebase -i master~14

After this, change the relate commit to r means update the commit message