# changing the commit message in git

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I edit an incorrect commit message in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git)

I am trying to edit the commit message for a previous commit.

this the git log output:

```
commit B
Author my name
date   2
message 2

commit A
Author my name
date   1
message 1
```

How to edit the message1?

Comment: git commit --amend -m "your new message"

Answer (score 0):

`git rebase -i HEAD^^` should give you option to change two last commits, then you can choose to amend commit A and change its log message. Note that this will change hash of both commit A and commit B, so if anyone has already pulled your changes, they will get weird conflicts.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that the `r` or `reword` action in `git rebase -i` is the easiest one if you just need to change the commit message.