# Fix comments of several commits with push.

Tags: git

My first language is not english and I'm working in a team whose first language isn't english either, but the documentation we are producing is in english.

One person of the team made an mistake and has been commiting and pushing everything he does in his own language. So i'd like to know if there's any way to ammend comments that date to about 3 months ago to this day.

Is it possible?

Comment: Your answer can be found in this http://stackoverflow.com/a/180085/1116

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to change the commit comments? Or text inside committed files.

Comment: And that's what happens if you let people commit to your main repository without anyone reviewing their commits...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this without requiring *everyone* who already pulled those commits to fix stuff. Rewriting history is *srs bsns*. Consider if you *really* need to fix those commit messages - are people likely to need them in the future and unable to paste them into google translator? If not, it's not worth the trouble.

Anyway, the way to do it is `git rebase -i HEAD~x` with `x` being the number of commits you want to go back. Then you get an editor window where you replace `pick` with `reword`. After saving+existing you'll be able to edit each commit message.