# Is there any way to change commit message for a specific commit in git?

Tags: git

I want to change the commit message of a commit which I did earlier and pushed to origin/master. now I have done a couple of commits and push(s) after that. Is there any way to change the commit message of second last or third last push that was made to master?

Comment: [Rebase](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing). Is this a shared repo? If so, others won't be happy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git

Second or third answer.

Comment: The third answer is the one you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git/180085#180085 - and remember to read the comments discussing what to do if you've already pushed the commit upstream.

Comment: No, you cannot change commits you pushed and changing a commit message counts as changing the commit.