# Edit a commit message in SourceTree Windows (already pushed to remote)

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

How do I edit an incorrect commit message in SourceTree without touching the command line?

**Additional details:**

- This is not the latest commit.
- Everything was already pushed to Bitbucket.
- This is a private repository and I am the only collaborator.
- I don't mind losing any of the previous commits, as I can re-commit them anytime.
- I don't want however to lose any code modification ever made.

**Outcome:**

- As it seems impossible at the moment according to your comments and replies, I'm going to create a new repository and start all over. Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 545, accepted):

Here are the steps to edit the commit message of a previous commit (***which is
not the most recent commit***) using **SourceTree for Windows version 1.5.2.0**:

### Step 1

Select the commit ***immediately before*** the commit that you want to edit.
For example, if I want to edit the commit with message "FOOBAR!" then I need
to select the commit that comes right before it:

[image: Selecting commit before the one that I want to edit.]

### Step 2

Right-click on the selected commit and click `Rebase children...interactively`:

[image: Selecting "Rebase children interactively".]

### Step 3

Select the commit that you want to edit, then click `Edit Message` at the
bottom. In this case, I'm selecting the commit with the message "FOOBAR!":

[image: Select the commit that you want to edit.]

### Step 4

Edit the commit message, and then click `OK`. In my example, I've added
"SHAZBOT! SKADOOSH!"

[image: Edit the commit message]

### Step 5

When you return to interactive rebase window, click on `OK` to finish the
rebase:

[image: Click OK to finish.]

### Step 6

At this point, you'll need to force-push your new changes since you've rebased
commits that you've already pushed. However, the current 1.5.2.0 version of
SourceTree for Windows does not allow you to force-push through the GUI, so
you'll need to use Git from the command line anyways in order to do that.

Click `Terminal` from the GUI to open up a terminal.

[image: Click Terminal]

### Step 7

From the terminal force-push with the following command,

```
git push origin <branch> -f
```

where `<branch>` is the name of the branch that you want to push, and `-f` means
to force the push. The force push ***will overwrite*** your commits on your
remote repo, but that's OK in your case since you said that you're not sharing
your repo with other people.

**That's it! You're done!**

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer! However, I'm using SourceTree 1.5.2 and whenever I right-click on the latest commit, the `Rebase children...interactively` menu is grayed out: http://i.imgur.com/phdi1rE.png

Comment: Sorry I missed your Step 1, which is to select the commit **under** the one that we want to edit! Ok but now I have another issue, when I click on `Rebase children...interactively` I get the following error: _"Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes."_ — I do have uncommitted changes but I don't want to commit them right now, are there any workarounds? Thank you!

Comment: Stash the changes. There's a button in SourceTree for it. You can then re-apply the changes after the rebase. Note that this won't stash untracked files though. You can stash untracked files from the command line, but the current version of SourceTree doesn't make that sort of thing available through the GUI.

Comment: I've accepted and upvoted your answer for the great effort you provided, but just for information I'm still unable to edit a commit on SourceTree, it seems too complicated and it appears easier to me to just create a new repository from scratch start over.

Comment: @Failedtofetchusernamein'' fair enough. When you say that you're "still unable to edit a commit", is that because something was wrong with my instructions, or is it only because the process is too complicated?

Comment: @ Cupcake I'm still unable to edit commits because I have uncommitted files and also untracked files, and I'm not sure what stashing means nor how to revert it, nor do I want to use the command line...

Comment: The steps are basically the same on the Mac version, too.

Comment: Beware: If you want to start your commit message with # this won't work, git treats it as a comment and tells you your commit message is empty!

Comment: "That's it! You're done! " - It's so easy as i don't know what, as a catch a rabbit may be. Instead of creating program feature, for such an important and often seeing situation. When you have just made typo in a hurry, you have to reset head and create new commit again.

Comment: Funny - I wonder why they don't make a simple "Edit Commit Message" option.

Comment: I wanted to edit a commit message on Mac client, which I hadn't already pushed but it wasn't the last commit and following this answer step 5 did the job for me :) Thanks

Comment: Does this still work on 1.9.6.1? It isn't for me, just wondering if it is a bug or I am doing something wrong...

Comment: Force Push is now available though the GUI. Otherwise PERFECT :-)

Comment: You said "The force push will overwrite your commits on your remote repo, but that's OK in your case since you said that you're not sharing your repo with other people."
What will happen to the repo if you ARE sharing your repo with other people? Will it name you as the author of all commits following the edited commit?

Comment: I don't think I missed any step here, but the new commit messages got recreated, but the older commit history remains that I was trying to edit still remain ...

Comment: Step 8: Discover that the terminal button doesn't work.  Realize that Atlassian makes buggy software. Go to https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Terminal-button-in-SourceTree-fails-to-launch-a-terminal/qaq-p/113865 and follow the directions to fix the terminal button.

Comment: @SethCoast yes, you'll become the author of all commits. Another fun fact/drawback: all commits will have a date of the moment you commit the rebase, so you lose history on that as well. It's really too bad there's not a way to just modify a comment without altering so much else.

Comment: @LaTisha "Force Push is now available though the GUI." - can you show us where ?

Comment: Yeah @LaTisha where is the Force Push option?

Comment: @Jono you need to enable it under the options. See https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/How-to-quot-force-quot-push/qaq-p/718539 and if you are using SourceTree on a Mac, the option is under the Advanced tab of the Preferences. Once done, you should be able to push all of the latest changes and an option checkbox on the slide-down modal for pushing will appear to allow you to force push.

Comment: I had to do a Pull on the repo at the end to get SourceTree (v3.4.8) to correctly refresh, otherwise, perfect answer.  Thanks.

Comment: **What to do if you have only one commit node, and you want to edit message for that one?**

Answer (score 70):

On Version 1.9.6.1. For UnPushed commit.

1. Click on previously committed description
2. Click Commit icon
3. Enter new commit message, and choose "**Amend latest commit**" from the Commit options dropdown.
4. Commit your message.

Comment: I think this is the more accurate one since basically mimics what `git --amend -m 'new message...'` command does when from the terminal. But the step number 1 is not required, you can click on which ever commit you want, but the `Ammend latest commit` does the trick for you updating the very lsat one.

Comment: thanks!.. the best answer! .. Only one detail, in step 3 first choose "Ammed latest commit" and then enter new commit message ;)

Answer (score 22):

If the comment message includes **non-English** characters, using method provided by user456814, those characters will be replaced by question marks. (tested under sourcetree Ver2.5.5.0)

So I have to use the following method.

**CAUTION**: if the commit has been pulled by other members, changes below might cause chaos for them.

**Step1**: In the sourcetree main window, locate your repo tab, and click the "**terminal**" button to open the git command console.

**Step2**:

***[Situation A]***: target commit is the latest one.

**1)** In the git command console, input

```
git commit --amend -m "new comment message"
```

**2)** If the target commit has been pushed to remote, you have to push again by force. In the git command console, input

```
git push --force
```

***[Situation B]***: target commit is not the latest one.

**1)** In the git command console, input

```
git rebase -i HEAD~n
```

It is to squash the latest *n* commits. e.g. if you want to edit the message before the last one, *n* is 2.
This command will open a vi window, the first word of each line is "**pick**", and you change the "pick" to "**reword**" for the line you want to edit. Then, input `:wq` to save&quit that vi window. Now, a new vi window will be open, in this window you input your new message. Also use `:wq` to save&quit.

**2)** If the target commit has been pushed to remote, you have to push again by force. In the git command console, input

```
git push --force
```

**Finally**: In the sourcetree main window, Press `F5` to refresh.

Comment: question says "without touching the command line".

Answer (score 13):

### Update

**Note: this answer was originally written with regard to older versions of SourceTree for Windows, and is now out-of-date.**

[See my new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23239109/456814) for the current version of SourceTree for Windows, **1.5.2.0**. I'm leaving this answer behind for historical purposes.

### Original Answer

> as I'm on Windows I don't have a command line tool nor do I know how to use one :( Is it the only way to get that sorted out? The GUI doesn't cover all the git's functions? — [Original Poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604232/git-how-to-edit-a-commit-message-in-sourcetree-windows-already-pushed-to-bitbuc#comment25625394_17604232)

Regarding Git GUIs, ***no, they don't cover all of Git's functions***. ***They don't even come close***. [I suggest you check out one of the answers in How do I edit an incorrect commit message in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git), Git is flexible enough that there are multiple solutions...from the command line.

SourceTree might actually come with the msysgit bash shell already, or it might be able to use the standard Windows command shell.  Either way, you open it up form SourceTree by clicking the Terminal button:

[image]

You set which terminal SourceTree uses (bash or Windows) here:

[image]

### One way to solve the problem in SourceTree

That being said, here's one way you can do it in SourceTree. Since you mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604232/git-how-to-edit-a-commit-message-in-sourcetree-windows-already-pushed-to-bitbuc#comment25624119_17604232) that you don't mind "reverting back to the faulty commit" (by which I assume you actually mean resetting, which is a different operation in Git), then here are the steps:

1. Do a hard reset in SourceTree to the bad commit by right-clicking on it and selecting `Reset current branch to this commit`, and selecting the hard reset option from the drop down. [image]
2. Click the Commit button, then
3. Click on the checkbox at the bottom that says "Amend latest commit". [image]
4. Make the changes you want to the message, then click Commit again. Voila!

Regarding [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604232/git-how-to-edit-a-commit-message-in-sourcetree-windows-already-pushed-to-bitbuc/17608431#comment25624119_17604232):

> if it's not possible because it's already pushed to Bitbucket, I would not mind creating a new repository and starting over.

Does this mean that you're the only person working on the repo? This is important because it's not trivial to change the history of a repo (like by amending a commit) without causing problems for your collaborators.  However, assuming that you're the only person working on the repo, then the next thing you would want to do is force push your changed history to the remote.

Be aware, though, that because you did a hard reset to the faulty commit, then force pushing causes you to lose all work that come after it previously.  If that's okay, then you might need to use the following command at the command line to do the force push, because I couldn't find an option to do it in SourceTree:

```
git push remote-repo head -f
```

This also assumes that BitBucket will allow you to force push to a repo.

You should really learn how to use Git from the command line anyways though, it'll make you more proficient in Git. #ProTip, use msysgit and turn on Quick Edit mode on in the terminal properties, so that you can double click to highlight a line of text, right click to copy, and right click again to paste. It's pretty quick.