# How to amend a specific commit message in Git?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to change a commit message in [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) but cannot find where the option is. It has not been pushed yet.

How can I amend the message for older commits in SourceTree or command line?

Comment: Take a look at this specific answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23239109/2275011

Answer (score 9):

There is no feature to do that because how git internally work, a sha1 sealing each commit.

But you could :

- do a 'amend' if the message is the one of the last commit.
- do a `git rebase -i` also named a rebase interactive and choose 'reword' (or 'r') for each commit you want to rewrite the commit message.
- use git 'notes' to join a new comment next to the existing one (but handle it is not straightforward because you have to push the note explicitely and query them also to see them... )

Comment: Surprising that it's not easily possible, but good to know that so I can stop searching.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the branch is like `A-B-C-D-E` and you want to amend C. Here is one solution I prefer:

```
git reset C --hard
#do some changes and add
git commit --amend
git cherry-pick C..E
#or git cherry-pick D E
```

Answer (score 2):

## Steps

Please follow the following steps to edit the commit message of previous commits

### Step-1

On the command line, navigate to the repository that contains the commit you want to amend.

Use the `git rebase -i HEAD~n` command to display a list of the last n commits in your default text editor.

For example

```bash
# Displays a list of the last 3 commits on the current branch
$ git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

### Step-2

The list will look similar to the following:

```bash
pick e499d89 Delete CNAME
pick 0c39034 Better README
pick f7fde4a Change the commit message but push the same commit.

# Rebase 9fdb3bd..f7fde4a onto 9fdb3bd
#
# Commands:
# p, pick = use commit
# r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

### Step-3

Replace `pick` with `reword` before each commit message you want to change.

**NOTE**: If you are using VIM then press `i` to be able to edit the file. Then proceed to replace `pick` with `reword` and press `ESC` once the changes are made.

### Step-4

Save and close the commit list file. (Use `:wq` to save and quit vim)

### Step-5

In each resulting commit file, type the new commit message, save the file, and close it.

### Step-6

When you're ready to push your changes to GitHub, use the push --force command to force push over the old commit.

```bash
$ git push --force origin EXAMPLE-BRANCH
```

## Reference

1. [How to edit an older commit's message](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/committing-changes-to-your-project/creating-and-editing-commits/changing-a-commit-message)

Answer (score 1):

1. Find that commit, using `git reflog` and then find its sha-id
2. To go to that commit , use

   `git reset --hard sha-id` (if you don't want to keep the changes of the current state)

   ***or,***

   use `git reset --soft sha-id` (if you want to keep the changes)
3. Now do a commit --amend to the commit.....
4. Now, check if that the commit , you are amending to, has already been pushed or not,

   if, **YES**, then do a rebase and push it...

   ```
      `git push ` and revert back your head to where it was earlier using its sha-id
   ```

   *If you don't do the above step, your branch will diverge from the remote and you will see that in the `git status`*

   else, just revert back to your commit using its sha-id