# Change the wrong commit message in Git

Tags: git, commit

I a have a small problem with **Git commit**. So I am working on some project and using **Git**. I did a **Git commit** and I accidentally wrote a **wrong** commit message. So my question is:

> Is there anyway I can change the commit message in Git?

**NOTE:** I have tried to do this way:

```
git commit -a --amend -m "New Commit Message"
```

But it doesn't work. Why?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything from [How do I edit an incorrect commit message in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git). If your amend didn't work, did you get any error messages? Are you trying to change a commit message from a commit that comes before your most recent commit?

Comment: ok, sorry i didn't saw this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lose the first `-a` you aren't adding any files, you're just changing the HEAD commit:

```
git commit --amend -m"New Commit Message"
```

Comment: The `-a` isn't a problem, it will work with it, even if the original poster isn't committing anything new.