# git: How to change the commit message of an already committed file, non interactively?

Tags: git

I have a situation where a committed file is reviewed by the bug tracker tool and once it reviews the commit message has to change.

So my question is, Is there a way to change the commit message of a file that is already committed into my local git repository?

Comment: Asked earlier you could have earned a lot of rep: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git

Comment: Usually you don't want to change the commit message, because that changes the commit ID, with all sorts of complex consequences. Rather, use `git notes`.

Comment: @sleske the original poster wants to change the message for a local commit, which happens all the time, it's fine, as long as the commit isn't shared by anyone else.

Comment: @Cupcake: True. The mention of "reviewed by the bug tracker tool" made me think that this probably happens after pushing the commit to some central server, because a bug tracker usually runs on a central server, and cannot access developer's local repos. I may have guessed wrong, of course.

Answer (score 7):

If your commit is at the tip (no other changes committed since) you can:

```
git commit --amend -m "New commit message"
```

If other changes have been committed since:

```
git rebase -i <commit-to-change>~
```

This will fire up an editor.  Replace pick with edit on the correct commit entry, save and exit.  Then:

```
git commit --amend -m "New commit message"
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the aid of the editor, by passing the commit message as an argument directly to the git rebase -i command. Like for example git rebase -i <commitid> <new_commit_message> should replace the commit message of that particular commit.

Comment: `git rebase -i` is what you would use if you had more commits since the one you wanted to edit.  It allows for editing more than one commit at once.  I have written scripts that do similar things to what you are looking for, I gave you simplest answer to your question.

Comment: assuming the commit is already done on the client machine, what i am looking for is a command/script which accepts commitid and changes the commit message for that particular commit. Can you please share the script if you have it?

Comment: is it also possible to change the commit message without changing the commit id?

Comment: It is not possible to change the commit message without changing the commit id.  The commit id is generated and the log message is a part of the formula.

Comment: The scripts that I have are very manual in nature when it comes to resolving conflicts and dealing with merges.  The closest one that I have will do a `git reset --hard <rev>`, which if there are conflicts, you cannot get back to the original state.  In fact if my task was to do what you are asking, I use the `git rebase -i` method that I mentioned.  With `git rebase -i` if I want to just go back to the way things were I can just do `git rebase --abort`.