# How can I edit my previous commit in Git?

Tags: git

Here's what I did:

1. Fix a bug by edit a file.
2. `git commit -a -m "comment ... "` and `git push`
3. After I pushed this commit , I found I've missed something, so I need to re-edit the file and push it again.
4. The problem is, I don't want to create a new commit, is `--amend` a good choice ?

Comment: IIRC, amend works only if you haven't pushed yet

Comment: Ammend also works if you have pushed it already..you can force push it..but I would not recommend that..depends on the internal workflow..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I edit an incorrect commit message in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an interactive rebase and squash last 2 commit messages as follows

```
//commit with  your new changes
git commit 

git rebase -i HEAD~2

//This launches an interactive rebase where you can squash your last 2 commits into a single commit.
```

Now, you git will run you through last 2 commits, and you can squash them(among other options like reword etc).

**Note:** Do not rebase if you have pushed your commit to a server.

Comment: Do you mean I shouldn't try to amend new changes after push ?

Comment: If you have pushed your commit, do not rebase or change the existing commit. This will lead to confusion. It is better to have a new commit. As long as you haven't pushed changing commit messages is fine.

Comment: @palerdot this isn't true. `git commit --amend` can change file contents as well. Edit stuff, `git add` the affected files (or `git rm` if you want to remove stuff), then `git commit --amend`. The rebase is needlessly complicated.

Comment: If you really want to do it, you can delete the remote branch, squash the commit in your local and then push the branch to server. You can only think about doing it if no one has pulled the previous commit you made.

Comment: @palerdot and that's just overly dogmatic. There are plenty of situations where you *can* safely push a revised history. For example, on a private project where you can contact the people who might be affected, or just when nobody really cares :)

Comment: @hobbs I was actually mistaken about `git commit --amend`. You can change files as you say. But, if you rebase an existing commit after being pushed to a server, it will result in needless complications right ? I just intended to give him an advice.

Comment: @MrROY probably `git commit --amend` after making your changes will be easier for you. I recommend amending your last commit too as rebasing is comparatively complicated. But remember, rebasing after pushing to a server is not really recommended if you ever decide to rebase.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can `git add` the edited file, `git commit --amend`, and then push again — as long as you don't mind editing public history, which could inconvenience some people. The server will probably reject a non-fast-forward push, but you can override it with `git push --force`, or if the server is configured to be very strict, by deleting the branch from the server and then pushing.

If rewriting history is not a reasonable option, just make a new commit and say "oops" :)

Comment: Now I think an "oops" commit is easier for me ... Thanks.