# How do I edit an incorrect commit message in Git without including any staged modifications?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-amend

If I have staged some changes, and in the process notice an error in my previous (and un-pushed) commit message, is there a way to amend the commit *without* folding in my staged changes?

I see various options on the man page for `git-commit` that perform a related function, but no combination that seems to produce exactly the desired effect:

- `--amend`
- `--all` (automatically stage), but no '`--none`'
- `--message`
- `--only` (only the specified paths)
- `--` <no-more-options>...

The option `--only` with an empty file list (which I don't know how to specify), would almost be right, but that might in any case **remove** changes from the last commit (which I don't want).

The naïve method is to `reset` and then `commit --amend`, but that requires repeating the staging work. Alternatively, I could commit my staged changes, and edit the no-longer-latest commit message via a `rebase`, but that seems a to be awkward and overkill for just editing a message.

I don't think `stash save` can help either, as `stash` does not seem able to preserve the distinction between staged and unstaged changes. (Unless it's possible to `stash` only what has been staged? Again, I don't see how to do that.)

This question is related to
[How to modify existing, unpushed commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git)
where there's plenty of useful information amongst the answers, but this, slightly different question is not addressed.

Any hints gratefully received; thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with `--amend --only`? It seems to do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `git-commit-tree` and `git-reset`:

```
git reset --soft `git commit-tree <tree-id> -m "new message" -p HEAD^`
```

`<tree-id>` is the root tree id of HEAD. You can get it by `git cat-file -p HEAD`

Comment: Could you inline <tree-id> like `git reset --soft $(git commit-tree $(git cat-file -p HEAD | grep tree | awk '{print $2}') -m "new message" -p HEAD^)` ?

Comment: I've added some explanatory notes below. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266734/#20270522 (formatted in a separate answer, but am accepting this answer)

Comment: If you want the tree id for a ref, append `^{tree}`, e.g. `HEAD^{tree}` or just a colon, `HEAD:`.

Answer (score 1):

I think stashing should remember what was staged and what's not, maybe you need to use `--no-keep-index`

```
git stash --no-keep-index
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried `git stash --keep-index` followed by `git stash`, which looked promising. Unfortunately the second `git stash pop` can't be invoked until after a `commit`. This might be good enough for some...

Comment: Oh, and `stash`ing does not preserve staged *versus* unstaged.

Comment: actually if you ask me, I never trust stashing, they did some dirty tricks on me before, I'd rather do a `git commit -m 'temp'` and then `rebase` and rename, then `git reset --soft` rather than do a stash

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to put this as a comment to @npcode's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266734/#20267034), but couldn't get the formatting right. What follows is heavily based on that answer...

Here's a finer-grained explanation, and one that allows the original commit message to be edited:

(1) $ `git cat-file -p HEAD | grep "^tree\b" | awk '{print $2}'`

prints the root tree id of HEAD `${tree-id}`, needed in step (4)

Optionally:

(2) $ `git log -1 --format="%B" > ci.txt`

dumps the old commit message in `ci.txt`, which can then be edited. Optionally and alternatively, and entirely new commit message file could be written.

(3) $ *`edit`*`ci.txt`

Then either

(4a) $ `git commit-tree ${tree-id} -F ci.txt -p HEAD^`

or

(4b) $ `git commit-tree ${tree-id} -m "<new message>" -p HEAD^`

to create a new commit object with commit message, respectively, from a file or directly on the command line.
Either of these commands
prints the id `${commit-id}` of the new commit, needed in step (5)

(5) $ `git reset --soft ${commit-id}`

to set the new commit as the current HEAD.

@npcode and @Daniel combine steps (1), (4b) and (5).

Answer (score 0):

You can just continue with your work and do an interactive rebase afterwards:

```
git rebase -i
```

in the list of commits you see replace `pick` with `reword` for all commits you want to reword.