# How to edit on very long ago commit log before push to the server

Tags: git, git-tower

Is there any easier way to edit commit log ? (like the log that red-arrow pointing at)

If yes, How to do  it in command line or in gittower ?

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Changing it will mess up the whole history (since that commit) and make it a pain for everyone who already has a clone of the repository, excluding you.

Comment: What if the log hasn't push to the server ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I edit an incorrect commit message in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git)

Comment: @poc: In this case you can use the answers in the linked question. (Don't know if it covers git-tower, though.)

Comment: @krlmr The answer is in the linked question, but it's not obvious.  Simply amending won't work for poc, he has to go through an interactive rebase.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you haven't pushed to the server, you can use:

```
git rebase -i f88232a^
```

This will interactively rebase all commits starting at f88232a.  The `^` is there to tell git to use the commit before f88232a as the root for the rebase operation.  When you run this command, you're going to see something like:

```
pick f88232a Update
pick 57bfaca Change, redirect to index after finishing create
pick d23c917 Add missing column: result
...
```

Change the first `pick` to `e` or `edit`.  Now you'll see

```
Stopped at f88232a... Update
You can amend the commit now, with

    git commit --amend

Once you are satisfied with your changes, run

    git rebase --continue
```

Now run

```
git commit --amend
```

Change your commit message & save, then run

```
git rebase --continue
```

Voila!  Please note you are re-writing history all the way down to f88232a.  Every commit from f88232a to the present will be replaced with a new commit with a new SHA.  If you have any branches, this will get ugly quick, as those will stay based off the old commits.  But it should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't an easy way to do it (doesn't mean that there isn't a way, but it revolves changing **every single commit after the offending commit**).

Git was originally designed to make it very hard to change history. Enforce better commit description rules next time. (You can use hooks to perform basic checking).