# How can I change 'updata' to update

Tags: git

I use

git commit -m "updata some files"

to commit a change of my project, but i write error word 'updata', I want to change it to 'update', so how can I do?

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not pushed the commit to a remote, you can `--amend` the last commit by running `git commit --amend -m 'updated the files: list of files'`

documentation:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things