# Edit incorrect commit message in GitHub for Windows

Tags: git, github, git-commit, github-for-windows, git-amend

I've managed to muck up a commit message bad enough, that when I read it back, even I can't work out what is says!

This commit hasn't been pushed and I know that the message can be changed with:

```
git commit --amend -m "New commit message"
```

(thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git?newsletter=1&nlcode=125703%7cea0a) post)

However, I am using the GitHub for Windows GUI. So is there any way for me to change the commit message without jumping into powershell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from rolling back the entire commit and recreating it this is not possible in the UI. Rolling back performs an equivalent of `git reset HEAD^`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I just gave it a go and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 7):

For those using github for windows version 2.3 and upper, the rollback command has been removed, so click on the cog wheel then click on "**Undo most recent commit**".

Note that this will undo only the last commit if you committed more than once so it is not possible to change the message on previous commits.