# How to Change or Edit the Message on a Commit Before Pushing It

Tags: git-extensions

I need to edit my message/comment on a commit that I have not pushed.

I am using **Git Extensions**.

Help.

PS - Also, how do I edit my message after I push my commit?

Comment: This might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git

Comment: Thanks Chris, but I am looking to do this in Git Extensions (GUI). Any other hints? Advice?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you go into the Commit screen, there should be a checkbox that says "Amend Commit" at the bottom, as can be seen below:

[image: picture].

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly for me to amend the immediately previous wrong commit message

Comment: I did it and then I click on "Commit & push" and a popup window opened saying something about perform different merge options.... I worried and I cancelled it but it created a new commit afterwards. Fortunately I could reset it. So I don't see that it is working. Please detail more the steps to follow.

Comment: You change the online repository, therefore you have to force push. Usually "Force push with lease" is the option to choose.

Answer (score 2):

`commit --amend` can be useful, see more about this [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial/rewriting-git-history#!commit-amend)

Comment: Is that accessible through the GUI?

Comment: There should be a amend last commit button. 

If there's not such amend button you can use the console
git commit -a --amend -m "My new commit message"

Comment: I am using Version 2.47.3, and I can't see a button like that. Thanks. I will keep looking.