# GitExtensions: How to change only the commit message of the last commit after committing and pushing it?

Tags: git, git-extensions

I am using [GitExtensions](https://gitextensions.github.io/) standalone app, and I have done a commit and I forgot to add a comment about some changes I have introduced in the commit. Now I am trying to modify ONLY the message of the last commit. How can I achieve this from GitExtensions?

I found that it can be done using a [git command](https://itnext.io/git-reword-commit-82f0773fb22b):

```
git commit --amend
```

but how from GitExtensions UI?

Comment: Be aware that `git commit --amend` doesn't only change the commit message. If you have any changes added to your index then those will also be applied to the new commit.

Comment: ```git commit --amend -m "Your_message_name"```

Comment: Please, I am trying to find a solution but using GitExtensions. Provide detailed steps. Screenshots will be highly appreciated. I did what is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34570358/1624552 As I have said there I did it, I checked ammend checkbox and then I clicked on "Commit & push" button. Afterwards a popup window opened saying something about perform different merge options.... I worried and I cancelled it but it created a new commit afterwards...

Comment: ... Fortunately I could reset it. I don't know why that popup window appeared saying to merge because I already committed all my changes previously and GitExtensions was saying that there were no changes. So I got very surprised that updating the message of the last commit GitExtensions was saying that.