# How to edit the remote branch comment on Git?

Tags: git, github, jira

I've committed a ticket on branch `xy123` with comment `"xy124:fixed the issue"` in Git. JIRA displays only the created branch `xy123` details not the committed files details but the committed files details are in branch `xy124`.

Now I want to edit or remove the comment on Git. How to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Edit an incorrect commit message in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do an interactive rebase locally:

`git rebase -i HEAD~3` (if the commit you want to edit is 3 commits behind), then mark it as `r` for `reword`, and change the commit message.

Once you've done that, you can do a
`git push --force origin xy123` "origin" being your remote's name.

I'm not sure if JIRA will get updated on your particular setup.