# Git amend/reword (without adding/changing files)

Tags: git, git-commit, git-rewrite-history, git-amend

Often I want to edit a commit message without having to re-select the file-set from the last commit.

```
git commit file1.c file2.c
```

Accidental typo in commit message.

```
git commit file1.c file2.c --amend
```

This works, but Id like not to have to re-select the file-set from the original commit, I once accidentally did `git commit -a --amend` and added many changes unintentionally.

I know about `git rebase -i HEAD~1` then replace `pick` with with `r` (re-word), but this ends up being a few steps.

Is there a way to re-word the last commit in one step without including any new files?

Comment: I decided that this question isn't an *exact* duplicate of [Edit an incorrect commit message in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git), since this question specifically requires that no new changes are added during the amend. Reopening for anyone who wants to answer.

Comment: As long as there’s no staged content, just run `git commit --amend`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Amending message without staged changes

As long as you don't have any changes staged in your staging area, you can simply use

```
git commit --amend
```

to edit your previous commit's message<sup>1</sup>.

#### Amending message even *with* staged changes

However, if you *do* have changes staged, then you can use the `--only` (or `-o`) flag in combination with `--amend` to only edit the message of the previous commit, without committing staged changes:

```bash
git commit --amend --only
git commit --amend -o # Shorter
```

This option was pointed out by [David Ongaro in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23824606/456814).

#### Documentation

As stated in the [`git commit` documentation](http://jk.gs/git-commit.html#_options) (emphasis mine):

> ```
> -o
> --only
> ```
>
> Make a commit only from the paths specified on the command line, disregarding any contents that have been staged so far. This is
>   the default mode of operation of *git commit* if any paths are given
>   on the command line, in which case this option can be omitted. **If
>   this option is specified together with *--amend*, then no paths need
>   to be specified, which can be used to amend the last commit without
>   committing changes that have already been staged.**

<sup>1</sup><sub>As mentioned by [Minitech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375679/git-amend-reword-without-adding-changing-files#comment39572019_25375679) and others.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Just use `git commit --amend` without any other arguments. It will open up the editor and you can change your commit message.

Comment: You have to watch out for accidentally committing staged content with that, FYI. So just make sure you check `git status` before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `git commit --amend -m <new commit message>`. Of course, the precaution is to ensure that there are no staged changes as mentioned in other answers.