# Change past git commit message without stashing current work

Tags: git, commit-message

If I want to change a past commit message, I know I can do

```
git reset HEAD .
git commit --amend -m "Correct commit message"
```

or

```
git stash save "WIP"
git rebase -i HEAD~
```

but is there any way to do it without stashing current work (or, for `--amend`, making sure no changes are staged)?

This is for a commit that hasn't yet been pushed (or has been pushed into a feature branch that hasn't yet been merged).

Comment: Are you asking about an already-`push`ed or not-yet-`push`ed commit?

Comment: @eirikir not yet pushed.

Comment: @eirikir I've mentioned some details in this question that are in addition to what's in that question. I've also mentioned why I suspect `git commit --amend` and `git rebase` may not be suitable in this case.

Comment: Sorry! I was reading fast and missed that part. Idk how to edit my flag, but I think the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25375850/1569930

Answer (score 0):

It can depend on whether you've pushed the changes up to the remote already or not.

If you haven't you can simply use the command `git commit --amend` on the CLI. Else you could look into interactive rebasing.

There is some pretty good info over on [help.github.com](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-commit-message/) about changing commit messages which can be seen [here](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-commit-message/).

Hope that helps!