# git commit with conflicts message in log

Tags: git

I had some commits in one `branch A` and did all the development there.
Then there was a need to switch to another `branch B`. It was the same branch as mine but it did not have one - last commit that was in `branch A`.
So I decided to perform `cherry-pick` for that commit from `branch A`.

I had some conflicts and I resolved it. However in my log I have

```
Author: 
Date:  

    Commit message from branch A

    Conflicts:
        file.txt
```

How to get rid of this information about conflicts? Or is it possible at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Edit an incorrect commit message in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git)

Comment: But message is correct - but I don't need `conflicts` information there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change the commit message using

```
git commit --amend
```

Comment: Erm...So `conflicts` information is a part of the message?

Comment: I guess so. You just need to try it.

Answer (score 0):

That is just the commit message. The commit message can be changed before you commit.

If you have already committed but have not pushed, you can use:

`git commit --amend -m "New commit message"`