# Amend commit message from older commits using SHA ID

Tags: git, commit

Let's assume i have 3 commits:

```
Added bar.txt     (3)
Second Commit     (2)
Initial Commit    (1)
```

How can i change the commit message from `(2)` by using its SHA ID?
The commit was not pushed to the remote repository yet.

I tried: `git commit --amend -m "Added foo.txt" 8457931`

`8457931` are the first 7 numbers from the SHA ID.

Reason why this is not a duplicate:
I ask on how to change the commit message by using the SHA ID to point at the commit which i would like to change, unlike in the linked question.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/180085/558021), you'll have to perform an interactive rebase - this will bring up an interface that will let you edit older commits after which it will "replay" all of those commits and use your new commit messages...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edit an incorrect commit message in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git)

Comment: Hmm okay, but this does not show how to amend it by using the SHA ID.

Comment: When you are inside the rebase, you'll be presented with a list of commits including their SHA. You can't access a specific commit without taking into consideration the tree that it is a part of. Once you have your list of commits in the rebase, you'll be able to find your SHA ID. You'll need to initiate the rebase on the commit *before* the one you want to change.

Comment: Just to clear this up: the fact that there is a suggested duplicate for your question doesn't necessarily mean that you are asking the exact same question but rather than an **answer** on that other question would be enough to answer **this** question. Your edit is not really needed - it would be a good thing to remove it.

Comment: It said that i have to edit my question to show why it is not a duplicate tho.

Comment: The fact is that in the context of [so] - because the other post **does** contain an answer to your question - it is indeed a duplicate - this doesn't mean that it's a bad question at all.. It also doesn't mean that it needs to be deleted - it only means that an answer has already been provided elsewhere.

Comment: I can't find the answer for my question on the linked page, can you show me where it is?

Comment: I already linked to it in my first comment. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git/180085#180085 (it's not the accepted answer - but it **is** your solution)

Comment: I just searched the whole page for SHA but none of the results answered my question, sry.

Comment: There is nothing to search - the link I provided points directly to the answer. If you read it - you'll see. The answer uses the variable `$parent_of_flawed_commit` in place of an actual SHA ID. There is no copy paste answer for this - you'll need to understand exactly what you are doing since you are actually intending to change the history of a repository.

Comment: Thanks to you and the answer of Vasfed i understand now how it works. Thank you! :)

Comment: Just an FYI:  the duplicate question [contains the same answer that you've accepted.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/180085/1079354)

Comment: No it doesn't, it contains a little part of it, it does not show how to get the parent ID, i edited the accepted answer and added the other necessary part for the solution to it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do an interactive rebase, it is described in https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

Mark all as 'pick'(just retain that commit) or 'reword' for changing message. Note that all these commits will be rewritten, so it's better not to go deeper than `origin/HEAD` points

EDIT: you need to rebase on parent of the commit in question (note the `~1` after sha)

```
git rebase --interactive <your_sha>~1
```

Now a file opens:

```
pick b35b85c second commit
pick 9cc745b Initial commit
```

Search the line where your target commit is and change `pick` to `reword`:

```
reword b35b85c second commit
pick 9cc745b Initial commit
```

Save the file. Now another file opens, delete the first line and replace it with your new commit message. Save the file. Done.

Comment: Okay thank you, but this does not answer my question on how to amend the message by using the SHA ID, is it even possible?

Comment: You cannot change single commit if it is not on top of branch, all commits that point to it have to be rewritten.

Comment: Okay so it is impossible to solve it by just using the SHA ID to point at the commit which message i want to change?

Comment: Get its parent via `git cat-file -p <sha>` and `rebase -i` on it, your commit will be at bottom of commit selection

Comment: Your explanation was more confusing then necessary but now thx to @Lix i understand how it works. Thanks!

Comment: cat-file and grep to get the parent SHA ??

Comment: @AndrewC why not? Works perfect for me

Comment: @EdwardBlack - because Git provides SHA~1 to do the same, which doesn't fork a new process, and doesn't involve unreliable regex

Comment: For a one-off job - whatever floats you boat, actually I agree `<sha>~1` is cleaner

Comment: @Vasfed, how can i make use of this trick? Does it work like this: `git rebase --interactive SHA~1` ?