# git push fails after pulling from remote branch

Tags: git

I created a branch and made a commit a couple days ago.  I made some minor changes since that commit so I'm just doing `git commit --amend`.  However, when I push to the remote branch, it fails with `tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart`.  I did run `git pull` prior to initiating the commit.  I think I can do a `git push --force-with-lease` to get it going, but I want to figure out why git push isn't working on its own.

`git log $branchname:
commit 79c6414
commit db3812b
Merge: b50a40d 44768b2
commit b50a40d
Merge: 2858711 e581ab6`

`git log origin/branchname:
commit 73a86aa
commit db3812b
Merge: b50a40d 44768b2
commit b50a40d
Merge: 2858711 e581ab6`

Comment: Run `git fetch` to update your information about the remote and then share your `git log $branchName` and `git log origin/$branchName` if you can.

Comment: As it stands, a lot of information is missing from this question.

Comment: @Whymarrh updated the question with your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already pushed the previous commits to the remote server. When you amend the local commit, there is one commit missing from your local but existing in the remote. That's why you are behind the remote counterpart. If you want to make the amends available on the remote server, you have to 
`git push <remote> <branch> --force`

I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/179147/1287369) is related.

Comment: Is this the commit thats missing locally 73a86aa?

Comment: @Brosef yes, i think it is

Comment: So that was the very first commit I made to the branch.  After some time I  made some changes and did `git commit --amend` and ended up with 79c6414.  I thought commit --amend is suppose to keep the shame SHA as the previous commit.

Comment: @Brosef that's a good question. Actually I am not 100% sure whether --amend will keep the same SHA. But I guess they are different, because the SHA is calculated based on the contents. Your --amend changed the content, thus the SHA should be different.

Answer (score -1):

Do another pull, and push again. This could be due to the unfortunate event of someone committing right before you pushed again.

Comment: I tried it 3 times, so I don't think thats the issue.