# How to recommit in git

Tags: git

I have commited some change with git. Now I would like to change the commit text. Is there any possibility to do that? I am using eclipse git and gittortoise

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edit an incorrect commit message in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git)

Comment: Use `git commit --amend` ... keep in mind this will _rewrite_ the HEAD of your branch, so when you push you will have to use `git push --force`

Comment: why there is a java tag?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you may use **git commit --amend -m "message"** or may do this which is fairly equivalent :

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD
$ ... do something else to come up with the right tree ...
$ git commit -c ORIG_HEAD
```