# Is it possible to setup git merge for automatic resolving? (git rerere)

Tags: git, powershell, command-line

I have 2 laptops with one plaintext file, which has to be synced - it is used as a database for a 3rd party software. Customer wants to sync the content of that file on a daily manner.

First idea was to make a script which would upload file to Dropbox, but in case of confilct (both users remove line A and first user add line B instead, second user add line C instead) Dropbox creates a separate file.
EDIT: was going to mention, but forgot to say: in case of conflict, both lines B and C should replace line A - "take both" strategy.

Second idea is to put file to repository, sounds easy, but i'm not sure how to setup auto resolving, because i don't want merge tool GUI to appear during the process.

Comment: are you allowed to override customer's modifications?

Comment: What would you want it to do in the case of conflicts? Use both lines B and C, choose one randomly, or something else?

Comment: @DavidDeutsch Thanks for reminding - somehow i forgot to add that to the question. Edited. Both B and C should be used instead of A, order is not important.

Comment: @JossefHarush Hi, which modifications? Customer has no idea about Git or Dropbox - well, maybe he has, but doesn't care - that's why i want to put everything into a script and run it from time to time - and that's why i want to avoid any extra GUIs so he would not be frightened.

Answer (score 4):

You have the `git rerere` command for your help.

This is exactly for this command is for.

#### [`git rerere`](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/fix-conflicts-only-once-with-git-rerere-7d116b2cec67#.d8f95i5j7)

**R**ecorded **R**eused **R**esolution

```
# enabled the option to record the 
git config --global rerere.enabled true
```

By the way, if you prefer rerere to auto-stage files it solved (I do), you can ask it to: you just need to tweak your configuration like so:

```
git config --global rerere.autoupdate true
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a solution, thanks, i'll check it this night.

Comment: Cool. There is a cool video about it in this series http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920017462.do

Answer (score 1):

If you want all conflicts resolved with changes from both sides being included, add the following to your `.gitattributes` file:

```
* merge=union
```

This will make git do what you want.

Comment: Regarding the documentation the file should be located in `$GIT_DIR/info/attributes` but  this folder only contains a file named "exclude". So do you have to create file `.gitattributes`  first?