# How do you set the commit message when editing a text file in a Visual Studio Teams Services git repository? (Visual Studio Online)

Tags: edit, azure-devops, git-commit

When browsing a repository under the "Code" tab of a project in Visual Studio Team Services. If I browse to a text file in the git repository and select it I see the contents of the file and I have the option to edit the file.

If I edit the file and then save it a git commit message is automatically generated, which is of the form `"Updated PreBuild.ps"` - if I edited the file `Prebuild.ps`

I like my git commit messages to be written in the future tense:

If this commit is accepted it will ***update PreBuild.ps to add some console logging***

How do I either type my own commit message or edit the commit message after it has been created in Visual Studio Team Services?

Comment: You can enter the commit message just above the code, left of the save icon.

Comment: @gdir you should have answered the question, your answer (in a comment) was correct.

Comment: Don't know why this question has a close vote, just because it is simple doesn't mean it should be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enter the commit message by editing the string "Updated PreBuild.ps" directly before saving the updated file. And you can also click dropdown icon to add more detailed description if you want.
[image]

And there isn't anyway to edit the commit message from VSTS Web Portal, you need to pull the changes to local and use "git commit --amend" command to update the commit message and then force push it back to remote. You can refer to this question for details: [Edit an incorrect commit message in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git)