# Git cluster several commits into a single commit

Tags: git, svn

I've added several consecutive incremental changes in my Git project that all share the same description (I.e. a false bug fix, followed by bug refix commit).

Is there any prompt method to select all those change into a single commit message after they were already (before or after they were pushed to central repository) ?

this way, I shell avoid multiple records on my project git history log, that all linked to the same issue. Instead, I'll get a single a single commit that contain all those incremental changes.

I also like to know if this can be done svn tool.

thanks

Comment: Are you trying to squash the commits into one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this question: [How to modify existing, unpushed commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git?rq=1)

For git, you can just rebase.
check with `git log` the commits. Let 'abdc237ze782he32uhe' be your **last commit**, you do **not** want to be part of this "gathering".
Then command:
`git rebase abcd -i`

then you got a list:

- pick iehiuehd9 bugfix
- pick uiz98z445 bugfix 2
- pick 879834hu4 bugfix3

the last one is your last commit. Assuming you want to gather all to one commit, change as follows

- pick iehiuehd9 bugfix
- s uiz98z445 bugfix 2
- s 879834hu4 bugfix3

then save and follow the instructions.

result:
you will have just one commit ( in my example iehiuehd9 ), containing all your changes of all 's' commits.