# Public Function

Tags: php, string, function, class

I get an error on my class

> [31-Dec-2016 20:05:53 Africa/Casablanca] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'Private' (T_PRIVATE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in /home/address/main.php on line 5

Haven't added anything to the class yet

```
    <?php

  class Modeladdonmain extends Hand {

      public function Private() {

      }

      public function Poke() {

      }

      public function Whisper() {

      }

  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Why was this question upvoted?

Comment: @Martin I upvoted this because when I saw this code I was stunned it contained an error and wanted to test it out myself to see if I get the same error. Basically, because of how interesting it was to me.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas ok, but the reason as to why this error occurs is explained *in the error quoted by the OP*. It could be an interesting topic in general, but I don't think this question shows much worth `:-/`

Comment: @Martin I know that the reason is explained in the error but still, it looked quite strange to me. :) Speaking of effort, [some question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-to-modify-existing-unpushed-commits) are highly upvoted when content is minimal, so I think it's ok if I upvote one or two questions like this one. :)

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas hahaha -yeah you make good point- but just because it's common doesn't make it *Right* `;-)`. I'm not intending to have a go at you at all and respect both that you told me the reasons why and the reason itself. It was just on my first impression of the question I didn't see why it warrented a +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `Private()` contains special word `private` which is used for declaring members, etc.

Any other similar name would solve your issue. For example, instead of `Private()` you can use something like `privateFunction()` (if you're ok with that name).

Similarly, you can't use names like `Protected()` or `Public()`.

Comment: `pryvate` also work.

Comment: @Martin It works, I agree, but that name, though...

Comment: Yes, I was being silly.