# remove remote commits that are not HEAD

Tags: git, git-commit, git-remote, git-reset, git-revert

I have a tricky situation. I need to remove and re-commit some commits that I already pushed to github remote repo. But these commits are not HEAD anymore (people pushed theirs on top of it).

I understand I can do revert commits, therefore preserving the commit history. But the requirement is to let wrong commits *disappear*.

So:

```
D <- other people's commit
|
C <- B and C are wrong commits! They need to be removed
| <- The changes that should be preserved from B and C will be
B <- committed on top of D
|
A <- this was the initial state
```

To give more explanation, I'm using 2 different GitHub accounts for work/personal. I accidentally committed B and C to company repo using personal GitHub account. So, I need to remove these commits from non-employee account

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

The problem is that commit `D` has inside it the ID of commit `C`.  Anything you do to get rid of `B` and `C` will, if it's effective at all, *also* get rid of commit `D`.

You *can* copy commit `D` to a new `D'` that is a lot like `D` but:

1. removes the changes that were in `B` and `C`, and
2. uses `A` as its parent commit

but if and when you do that, you must coördinate with everyone else who *also* has commit `D` now, especially whoever wrote it, and get *all of them* to switch to the new `D'` copy that has `A` as its parent.

Usually this is not worth doing.  It's much too hard to get 47 other people to undo and redo all *their* work, just to compensate for a mistake you made earlier.  Just live with the mistake.

If the mistake is worse than getting everyone else mad at you for making them re-do all *their* work, see [How to modify existing, unpushed commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/179123/1256452)